# How to return value to the parent form

Tags: javascript

I have a popup form and need to return a value to the master form. The first statement works fine, but when I try to put the field name (`textAlert`) to a variable, I cannot get it to work. I tried all kinds of syntax. 
Please help. Thanks.

```
function DoReturnValue() 
{
    opener.MasterForm.textAlert.value = "Hello";     // WORKS

    /*   DOES NOT WORK
    var theField = "textAlert";
    opener.MasterForm(theField).value = "Haloha";
    opener.document.MasterForm.getElementById(theField).value = "Haloha";
    */
}
```

Comment: Thanks VisioN. It works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To access properties dynamically with a string variable as a name, use [square-bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation):

```
opener.MasterForm[theField].value = "Haloha";
```